# VisualSVN Remote Server Problems

Tags: svn, connection, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have installed and set up VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN on my PC and they are working fine locally but when I use my remote IP and try to access it in the web browser it doesn't work. I have port forwarded with the port of "8443" and taken firewalls down.

At the top of the GUI in VisualSVN Server Manager it displays this text "VisualSVN Server (Local)" not sure how to fix it though.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you access exactly the same URL as specified in GUI. Right click on repository name and select 'Copy URL to clipboard'
- Check that 'VisualSVN Server' windows service is running. Server Manager console (the GUI) can work without it, but repository won't be accessible
- Check that port 8443 is accessible outside. The simplest way to do this is by using

  telnet [host_name] 8443